# Attempt to de-reference a null object when traversing DescribeSObjectResult to check permissions

Tags: apex, unit-test, permissions, failing-tests

I have this method that checks a user's write permissions on an Apex controller. It works just fine at runtime. However, I'm writing a test to cover it (indirectly) and I'm getting a 'Attempt to de-reference a null object' error when I hit a certain field (`Primary_Contact__c`, a text field). The field exists, and is accessible to the user (read/write). The user running the code is me (admin) and I should have access to it based on object permissions and FLS.

Here's the code:

```
private static void checkWritePermissions(DescribeSObjectResult describeResult, String[] fields) {
    Map<String, SobjectField> fieldMap = describeResult.fields.getMap();
    List<String> affectedFields = new List<String>();
    if(DEBUG) System.debug('checkWritePermissions user: ' + UserInfo.getUserId());
    for(String field : fields) {
        if(DEBUG) System.debug('checkWritePermissions on field: \'' + field + '\'');

        if(field.trim().toLowerCase() != 'id' && !fieldMap.get(field).getDescribe().isUpdateable()) {
            affectedFields.add(field);
        }
    }
    if(affectedFields.size() > 0) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(String.format(NO_UPDATE_ACCESS_MESSAGE, new String[] { String.join(affectedFields, ',') } ));            
    }
}
```

It throws the error when it gets to this line, when it reaches the `Primary_Contact__c` field:

```
if(field.trim().toLowerCase() != 'id' && !fieldMap.get(field).getDescribe().isUpdateable())
```

I simplified the code and ran it in the Developer Console and there were no errors and I got the result I expected (i.e., I had access):

```
System.debug(Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.getMap().get('Primary_Contact__c').getDescribe().isUpdateable());
```

Why would I be getting this error only during my test?

Comment: How are you generating these values? It seems odd that you're calling `trim()` in one spot but not the other. If you expect whitespace, remove it from the value before trying to use it as a map key.

Comment: How is the list `fields` generated? Is it possible that there's spurious whitespace or punctuation in the test field list? If you debug the `fieldMap` dictionary, is the field there in test context?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the trimmed value in both places if you expect leading or trailing whitespace.

```
for (String field : input)
{
    String cleanField = field.trim();
    if (cleanField != 'Id' && !fieldMap.get(cleanField).getDescribe().isUpdateable())
    {
        throw new AuraHandledException('Some Message');
    }
}
```

A couple notes:

- Comparing values with `==` or `!=` is case-insensitive, so no need to call `toLowerCase()`.
- <s>There is really no need to cache a collection of fields which fail the access check. Just throw your error as soon as you find one.</s>
- It may make sense to still check if the field is not found and consider that an error, which would look slightly different:

  ```
  for (String field : input)
  {
      String cleanField = field.trim();
      SObjectField token == fieldMap.get(cleanField);
      if (cleanField != 'Id' && (token == null || !token.getDescribe().isUpdateable()))
      {
          throw new AuraHandledException('Some Message');
      }
  }
  ```
- It may make sense to alter your exception message to include the SObjectType from your input, as that would have made it easier to catch your error. Obviously you would have to update your format to accomodate.

  ```
  String label = describe.getLabel();
  String exceptionMessage = String.format(myNewFormatString, new List<String> {
      label, String.join(...)
  });
  ```

Comment: Thanks @Adrian, you make good points. I cache the fields so I can display them so we know which fields the user doesn't have access to.

Comment: @SwisherSweet Ah, fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, I somehow switched `Contact` for `Account` in the calling code, so the field really wasn't there afterall. It should be checking field permissions on the Account object.

Here's the code that was calling the `checkWritePermissions` before I corrected it:

```
// keep these fields up-to-date as more updatable fields are added to form
String[] updatebleFields = new String[] { 'Phone', 'Fax', 'Primary_Contact__c', 
    'Primary_Email__c', 'ShippingStreet', 'ShippingCity', 'ShippingState', 'ShippingPostalCode' };        
// check permissions
checkWritePermissions(Schema.SObjectType.Contact, updatebleFields);
```

Here's the correct version:

```
// keep these fields up-to-date as more updatable fields are added to form
String[] updatebleFields = new String[] { 'Phone', 'Fax', 'Primary_Contact__c', 
    'Primary_Email__c', 'ShippingStreet', 'ShippingCity', 'ShippingState', 'ShippingPostalCode' };        
// check permissions
checkWritePermissions(Schema.SObjectType.Account, updatebleFields);
```

Not sure how that got swapped, as it was working before. But, after changing to the correct `SObjectType`, the error went away and my tests pass.

Comment: FYI you can save some keystrokes by dropping `Schema` and just typing `SObjectType.Account`.